# ¿Cómo obtener datos de longitud dinámica despues de : en PHP?

Tags: php, php7

Me conecto por IMAP para obtener un correo que tiene el siguiente formato

```
Presentación

Más datos aquí
Contrato: nombre del contrato
Type: value
Type 2: value 2
Server: aquí específican un servidor FTP o SFTP
User: username
Password: password

Más datos aquí
Saludos.
```

A mí me interesa obtener los valores del server, user y password sin especificar la longitud de los mismos, es decir, me gustaría que fuese dinámico.

Actualmente tengo:

```
$keyServer = 'Server: ';
$posServer = strpos($content, $keyServer);
if($posServer !== false)
$serverValue = substr($content, $posServer + strlen($keyServer), 34);
```

Estoy haciendo pruebas con:

```
$result = explode(': ', $content);
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos sin especificar una longitud manualmente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar una expresión regular para obtener los datos que deseas con [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php).

Ejemplo para el servidor `/Server:\s*(.+)/`:

1. `/`: Esto marca el inicio y el final de la expresión regular. Sirve para indicar a PHP que estamos definiendo una expresión regular.
2. `Server:` y `User:`: Estas son cadenas literales que estamos buscando en el texto.
3. `\s*`: Esto coincide con cualquier espacio en blanco (espacios, tabulaciones, saltos de línea, etc.) que pueda aparecer después de los dos puntos y antes del contenido que queremos capturar. El asterisco * indica que puede haber cero o más espacios en blanco.
4. `(.+)`: Esto es lo que se conoce como un grupo de captura. Vamos a capturar (Extraer) todo lo que viene después de los dos puntos y los espacios en blanco. `.+` El punto `.` indica que capture cualquier caracter y el símbolo más `+` que lo haga una o más veces.

Yo uso [regex101](https://regex101.com/) para probar las expresiones regulares, es muy buena ya que a la derecha te explica cada parte de la expresión regular.

Ejemplo genérico utilizando el contenido de tu correo en un `string`:

```
<?php
$input_string = "Presentación\n\nMás datos aquí\nContrato: nombre del contrato\nType: value\nType 2: value 2\nServer: aquí específican un servidor FTP o SFTP\nUser: AlgunUsuario\nPassword: password\n\nMás datos aquí\nSaludos.";
echo "Contenido original del correo:\n";
echo $input_string . "\n";

// Definir una expresión regular para obtener el servidor y el usuario
$pattern_server = '/Server:\s*(.+)/';
$pattern_user = '/User:\s*(.+)/';

// Inicializar las variables donde se extraerán los valores
$server = "";
$user = "";

// Utilizar preg_match para extraer los valores de servidor y usuario
if (preg_match($pattern_server, $input_string, $matches_server)) {
    $server = trim($matches_server[1]);
}

if (preg_match($pattern_user, $input_string, $matches_user)) {
    $user = trim($matches_user[1]);
}

// Devolver los valores de servidor y usuario
echo "/********* Servidor y Usuario *********/\n";
echo "Server: " . $server . "\n";
echo "User: " . $user . "\n";


?>
```

Esto devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Contenido original del correo:
Presentación

Más datos aquí
Contrato: nombre del contrato
Type: value
Type 2: value 2
Server: aquí específican un servidor FTP o SFTP
User: AlgunUsuario
Password: password

Más datos aquí
Saludos.
/********* Servidor y Usuario *********/
Server: aquí específican un servidor FTP o SFTP
User: AlgunUsuario
```

Comment: Mejor es imposible, muchas gracias. Siempre me han resultado complicadas las expresiones regulares ¿Cómo podría aprender?

Comment: Utiliza la pagina que te puse, `regex101` y abre la documentación de las expresiones regulares, luego intenta y a la derecha revisa si las explicaciones de cada parte hacen lo que deseas. Para aprender a hacer algo lo primero es practicar, lo segundo es intentar explicarle a alguien lo aprendido. Al enseñar cualquier concepto lo solidificas en tu mente. Saludos!